# Update GitHub Action from set-output to GITHUB_OUTPUT

Tags: github-actions

I have tried everything I can thing of for variations of this and have not been able to find the right syntax.  I have a GitHub Actions workflow that currently has this step:

```
steps:
- name: Parse Assignee Properties
  id: assignee_properties
  uses: actions/github-script@v6
  with:
    script: |
      const assignees = context.payload.issue.assignees;
      const assigneeStrings = assignees.map(a => `{'login': '${a.login}', 'id': ${a.id}, 'url': '${a.html_url}'}`);
      const jsonArrayString = `[${assigneeStrings.join(', ')}]`;
      console.log(`::set-output name=assigneeJson::${jsonArrayString}`);
```

The above uses the old set-output command it is being removed.  The documentation examples at https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/ all use echo "::set-output name={name}::{value}" and how to change them.

I've tried that format in the above script, it returns an error that the syntax is wrong.  I tried different variables of using console.log like:

- `` console.log(`assigneeJson='${jsonArrayString}' >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`); ``
- `console.log("assigneeJson='${jsonArrayString}' >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT");`
- `console.log("assigneeJson='${jsonArrayString}'") >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT;`

And none work.  I'm guessing this is super simple and I'm missing something obvious but there appears to be very little documentation of using this within a script and using console.log.

Comment: did you try to set the output in this way instead? https://github.com/actions/github-script#reading-step-results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `console.log`, but [rely on the imported `@actions/core` library](https://github.com/actions/github-script#actionsgithub-script) using:

```
core.setOutput('outputKey', 'outputVal');
```

> To use this action, provide an input named script that contains the body of an asynchronous function call. The following arguments will be provided:
>
> - github A pre-authenticated octokit/rest.js client with pagination plugins
>   context An object containing the context of the workflow run
> - **core A reference to the @actions/core package**

[From the docs or @actions/core](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core):

> ## Inputs/Outputs
>
> Action inputs can be read with getInput which returns a string or getBooleanInput which parses a boolean based on the yaml 1.2 specification. If required set to be false, the input should have a default value in action.yml.
>
> Outputs can be set with setOutput which makes them available to be mapped into inputs of other actions to ensure they are decoupled.
>
> ```
> const myInput = core.getInput('inputName', { required: true });
> const myBooleanInput = core.getBooleanInput('booleanInputName', { required: true });
> const myMultilineInput = core.getMultilineInput('multilineInputName', { required: true });
> core.setOutput('outputKey', 'outputVal');
> ```

[Alternatively you can set the `setOutput` property of the `github-script` action](https://github.com/actions/github-script#reading-step-results):

```
- uses: actions/github-script@v6
  id: set-result
  with:
    script: return "Hello!"
    result-encoding: string
```

The return value will be auto-assigned to an output variable called `result`.

```
- name: Get result
  run: echo "${{steps.set-result.outputs.result}}"
```

This will work when you only need to assign a single value and when you don't care about the name being `result`.

Comment: Yeah, I was completely over thinking this one.  Using the return from the script is way easier.  I'll post a complete code example below for anyone else looking.

Answer (score 5):

One of those classic moments of posting a question and figuring it out right afterwards.  I used the return value.  So the code looks like:

```
steps:
- name: Parse Assignee Properties
  id: assignee_properties
  uses: actions/github-script@v6
  with:
    script: |
      const assignees = context.payload.issue.assignees;
      const assigneeStrings = assignees.map(a => `{'login': '${a.login}', 'id': ${a.id}, 'url': '${a.html_url}'}`);
      const jsonArrayString = `[${assigneeStrings.join(', ')}]`;
      return jsonArrayString;
    result-encoding: string
```

And later on you can call it like this:

```
${{ steps.assignee_properties.outputs.result }}
```